# How do I make Active Admin show code DRY across models?

Tags: activeadmin, dry

I have a number of models within Active Admin that have very similar (but not exactly the same) show pages along the lines of:

```
  show do |ad|
    attributes_table do
      row :name
      row :length
      row :width
      row :height
      ...
    end

    panel "Images" do
      text_node link_to 'Add Image', new_admin_image_path(...)
      table_for ad.images do
        column "Image" do |image|
          image_tag(...)
        end
        column do |data|
          link_to :edit, edit_admin_image_path(...)
        end
        column do |data|
          link_to :delete, admin_image_path(data), method: :delete
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

The 'panel "Images" do' code will be duplicated exactly within each model, so I'd like to put it somewhere else.  I've been going down the ViewHelper and render partial paths, but in both cases I end up with something that doesn't know what "panel", "text_node", "table_for", etc. is.  Guidance as to what is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arbre](https://github.com/gregbell/arbre), the template language ActiveAdmin uses, does support partials. You can
move the duplicated code into an `arb` partial such as
`app/views/admin/_images_panel.html.arb`. Then your ActiveAdmin resources
can simply call `render` with the partial path and any needed local
variables.

```
show do
  attributes_table do
    # ...
  end

  render 'admin/images_panel', data: data
end
```

The partial may also reference the generic method `resource` to eliminate
the need to pass in local variables. Resource is whatever resource the
admin is managing. For example:

```
panel "Images" do
  table_for resource.images do
    # Note use of `resource` instead of `ad` above.
    # ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Sorry for the delay, in the middle of some other changes, so I'll give this a go soon and mark the answer as correct.